# How do you setup Codeigniter to handle multiple projects with shared ci base?

Tags: php, codeigniter, subproject

I've seen several CI implementation examples that claim you can put project folders under the "applications" folder for Codeigniter.

However I've not been able to see this work as promised.

Here is what I have done and what I would like to do - maybe you can help out. For the sake of argument my document root is /www/(It's not, but let's use it for for simplicity's sake)

I've put the codeigniter core in /www/corelib/codeigniter

I've put the codeigniter system folder in /www/ci_system

I've put the applications directory in /www/applications

I've put my "entry point" in /www/dd

Now let's say I have two projects : "dataentry" and "cpanel"

The ideas is that I can go to

h**p://mydomain/dd/dataentry    // for the dataentry application and

h**p://mydomain/dd/cpanel       // for the cpanel application.

IF I organize the dataentry and cpanel directories like this:

/www/applications/controllers/dataentry

/www/applications/controllers/cpanel

/www/applications/models/dataentry

/www/applications/models/cpanel

/www/applications/views/dataentry

/www/applications/views/cpanel

I can get this to work fine.  However, what I would like to do is keep the model and view at the same level as the controller so that I would have the following:

/www/applications/dataentry/controllers

/www/applications/dataentry/models

/www/applications/dataentry/views

/www/applications/cpanel/controllers

/www/applications/cpanel/models

/www/applications/cpanel/views

This does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

-CF

Comment: 10 years is a long time.  What we were trying to do was minimize CI in every repository and having to update each project. In today's world, this is largely taken care of by Composer with CI being replaced by Laravel and SVN replaced by GIT.  And disk is cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - I've got this working as desired.  I'll try to write up a more extensive "how-to" and will provide a link in the comments section.

I did not have to modify .htaccess anymore than CI requires - I was happy about that.  My entry directory look like this:

/dd/index.php

The two key pieces are here:

```
list($blank, $webpath, $app) = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $application_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/applications/$app";
```

This allows a single index.php to handle all applications.

The part that I was missing is that appName must now also be the primary controller or be a directory within the controllers.  (The real problem I had was that I was hacking so much that I had configurations and routes preventing me from realizing what I was actually seeing : Sometimes starting clean is imperative.)

Answer (score 0):

Does each application ("dataentry" and "cpanel") have their own main index.php file which defines the appropriate $application_folder variable?

Also - and I'm sure you've read the docs - but [CodeIgniter's documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html) states that the /applications directory (or directories, in your case) should exist under the /system directory as follows:

```
system/application/foo/
system/application/foo/config/
system/application/foo/controllers/
system/application/foo/errors/
system/application/foo/libraries/
system/application/foo/models/
system/application/foo/views/
system/application/bar/
system/application/bar/config/
system/application/bar/controllers/
system/application/bar/errors/
system/application/bar/libraries/
system/application/bar/models/
system/application/bar/views/
```

Comment: The default location of the application directory is under the system directory - however this is variable and easily changed, and part of the "user configurable settings" in the primary index.php file.

Your first point - individual index.php files (or app-name files) is really at the heart of the problem.  I was hoping to avoid using them and keeping a single index.php file.  I am looking into creative uses of the .htaccess file now...
Thanks for your help!
-CF